# ruby on rails - Sorting by count product column in categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pls tell me how to sorting by count product column in categories. My category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many:category_products
  has_many:products, through: : category_products
```

My category_index.rb

```
has "COUNT(category_products.product_id)", as: :count, type: :integer
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, check if this is what you are looking for.

In controller:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:category_products)
              .select("categories.*, category_products.product_id, COUNT(category_products.product_id) product_count")
              .group('category_products.product_id')
              .order("product_count DESC")
```

Then in view:

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <p><%= category.product_count %> | <%= category.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

I don't know your `Category` column names.